# b2Body sinks into static body

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I have 2 static bodies, one on top of another.
When I switch the top one to dynamic, it sinks into the static for a second before recovering.

```
_boxBody->SetType(b2_dynamicBody);
_boxBody->SetAwake(true);
```

Why does this happen? And how can I prevent it? Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because static bodies do not collide, so there are no contacts between them until one becomes dynamic. Unfortunately it takes one time step for a contact to be established, and in that time step gravity also has a chance to act.

You might be able to avoid this by making the gravity scale of the dynamic body zero for the first step, but I think a better way would be to call Refilter on the fixtures of the dynamic body before stepping.

```
for (b2Fixture* f = body->GetFixtureList(); f; f = f->GetNext())
    f->Refilter();
```

(I haven't actually tried this myself, but I think that's what this Refilter function is for.)

Comment: It says `No member named 'Refilter' in 'b2Fixture'; did you mean 'm_filter'?`

Comment: Not sure which version you are using, but the latest version has it: http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Fixture.h

Comment: i have the latest cocos2dbox2d template. How do you update box2d alone?

Comment: There should be a folder containing the Box2D source, you can just replace it with the new source files. You might run into a problem with the slightly different debug draw handling in the new version, but there are a billion threads on various forums about that to google :)